# NLTK wrapper for Weka to build a classifier

Tags: weka, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I'm building a Named Entity classifier with `nltk` and I have my focus on location retrieval (of any type, from countries to museums, restaurants or roads). I'm trying to vary featuresets and methods I use.

For now, I've used NLTK's built-in `Maxent`, `NaiveBayes`, `PositiveNaiveBayes`, `DecisionTrees` and `SVM`. I'm using 40 different combinations of featuresets.

`Maxent` seems to be the best, but it's too slow. `nltk`'s `SVM` is for binary classification and I had some issues with pickling the final classifier. Then I tried `nltk`'s wrapper for `scikit-learn SVM`, but it didn't accept my inputs, I tried to adapt but had some float coercion problem.

Now, I'm considering to use `nltk`'s wrapper for `Weka`, but I don't know if it could give me some extremely different result worthy to try and don't have to much time. My question is, what advantages `Weka` has over `nltk`'s built-in classifiers?

Comment: Out of interest, what problems did you have with the scikit-learn wrapper? (Question coming from its author.)

Comment: @larsmans Sorry, I misexpressed, question edited now. It was 3 weeks ago, so I don't remember the details, but basically I used the same inputs, everything worked fine for `nltk`'s built-in classifier but not using scikit wrapper.

Comment: No need to apologise for anything -- I'd just like to know if there's anything I can either clear up for you or fix in the code. Could you maybe post some code and the error message in your question?